# Is there an online HBase server populated with data that I can practice on?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I downloaded the Cloudera VMWare image, but the HBase dataset is lacking.

Is there an online server somewhere that I can access in order to really grok the concept?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Cloudera live. It is free for 15 days and after that you have to pay for it. However you might have to load the data into HBase tables. There might be some sample data.

Comment: Can you please provide the link. I have singed up on "cloudera live" but not able to find from where I can practice HBASE, in some online terminal like thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is very expensive and there is no reason to keep such server. Depending on your needs, it would be better to upload data by your own hands.

There any many collections of free datasets. Here is the small piece of what you can Google:

- https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public
- http://www.kdnuggets.com/datasets/index.html
- http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/big-data-sets-available-for-free

I may assure you that is difficult to load data in your system. It may be in any format you have to learn how to work with it. You have to understand data's nature and structure. This is also good practice for sure.

Good luck.